# talend - log level of tLogRow - log4j

Tags: talend

I have a tLogRow component that logs the output of tSetGlobalVar and tContextDump.  I have exported the job, and in the zip file I found a log4j which makes me think it is using this for the tLogRow component.  Now, my question is how can I specify the log level for the tLogRow component? as I'll be only wanting to see its log on WARN or maybe DEBUG level.

And for my tLogRow component I have checked "Print content with log4j".
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @54l3d mentioned above, `tLogRow` component seems not be the ideal component for logging using log4j.  I have achieved this via tJava instead:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
logger.debug("MY_CONTEXT_NAME: " + context.MY_CONTEXT_NAME);
logger.debug("GLOBAL MAP paramA: " + globalMap.get("paramA"));
```

For the globalMap's values logging, please note that if the your tJava component that's performing the log is within the same subjob as the `tSetGlobalVar`, the value you have set will not be immediately reflected.  I was only able to log the values set when it is on a different subjob than `tSetGlobalVar`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the use case of [tLogRow](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/15.9+tLogRow) component, its just to dislay a flow to console. The check box of using `log4j` does not change the content of the output, its about to change the api of writing. To change the settings of `log4j` in Talend, you can go to the top left of screen, the menu `file` then `edit the project properties` and you find this screen :

[image: talend log4j project]

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post.  There is a checkbox for using log4j for tLogRow, I'm wondering how I can set its output to be on WARN or DEBUG. Thanks